# how to find what values were passed onto a store procedure at the last run

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-express

My web application is calling a store procedure but not returning the desired results in the ASP.net page. When i execute the store procedure in sql server by providing the same values, i get the desired result. Is there any way i could tell what values were passed onto the store procedure when it was called by the web page?

note: I am using sql server 2012 express.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spvolview] 
    @Gender nvarchar(50), 
    @Age int,
    @Country nvarchar(100)
AS 


select 
clinical_study.BRIEF_TITLE, clinical_study.OVERALL_STATUS, clinical_study.PHASE, clinical_study.STUDY_TYPE, clinical_study.GENDER, location_countries.COUNTRY, facilities.CITY
from clinical_study
inner join location_countries
ON clinical_study.NCT_ID=location_countries.NCT_ID
inner join facilities
on clinical_study.NCT_ID = facilities.NCT_ID
where (clinical_study.GENDER LIKE '%'+@Gender+'%' or clinical_study.GENDER like 'Both')
and clinical_study.HEALTHY_VOLUNTEERS <> 'No'
and clinical_study.OVERALL_STATUS like 'Rec%'
and @Age>(case when isnumeric(minimum_age)=1 then left(minimum_age,2) end) 
and @Age<(case when isnumeric(MAXIMUM_AGE)=1 then left(MAXIMUM_AGE,2) end)
and  location_countries.COUNTRY = @Country
```

Comment: You would need to add some kind of logging to the stored procedure, or (can't remember if you can with Express or not) use SQL Server Profiler to view the statements sent to the DB. A much simpler alternative would be to just debug your web page and check what parameters are being passed there. How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: data source added to a grid view, I have added break points to the application, it does show the values passed as the parameters which seems to be fine, but ideally I want to see what values were supplied to the store procedure in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "see what values were supplied to the store procedure in the database itself" as you wrote in your comment you can create a simple table and make your store procedure write the parameters' values in it:

1. create table where you will store values (for example use following code in a "New query" tab):

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TMP_LOG](
       [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Gender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
       [Age] [int] NULL,
       [Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL)
   ```
2. edit your stored procedure adding an `insert` statement at the beginning of your procedure (right before the `select` statement):

   ```
   insert into [dbo].[TMP_LOG] select  @Gender, @Age, @Country
   ```